# React componentWillUnmount() stops setInterval when the timer hits at 7

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval, react-component, react-lifecycle

**Unable to stop setInterval in react using componentWillUnmount() when the timer hits at 7**
**class component**

```
export default class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      counter:0
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.timerID = setInterval(
      () => this.timer(),
      1000
      );
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    if(this.state.counter===7){
      clearInterval(this.timerID);
    }
  }

  timer = () => {
    this.setState({
      counter: this.state.counter+1
    })
  }
```

Comment: React components are not meant to unmount themselves, you would need a wrapper component that state/props would use to render / or not..

Answer (score 1):

I think here is little misunderstanding, componentWillUnmount run its content when component unmount, and not unmount component when some conditions met.

To make this code work as expected, you need to unmount your component when `this.state.counter` will be equal to 7.

If you want to stop your counter to work when `this.state.counter` will be equal to 7, then try to look into componentDidUpdate it fire every time after component update, so it will work